# Sleep function Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, sleep

Is there a simple sleep function in Visual Basic that doens't involve thread.

Something similiar like there exists in:
C: `sleep(1);`

We also tried this code:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal milliseconds As Long)
' pause for 5 seconds
Sleep 5000
```

...but it didn't work.  It gave me this error:

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
>   Message: A call to PInvoke function
>   'Ganzenbordspel!Ganzenbordspel.Spel::Sleep'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is
>   likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged
>   target signature. Check that the
>   calling convention and parameters of
>   the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature.

Answer (score 42):

This one is much easie.

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
```

Answer (score 19):

Since you are asking about .NET, you should change the parameter from `Long` to `Integer`.  .NET's Integer is 32-bit.  (Classic VB's integer was only 16-bit.)

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal Milliseconds As Integer)
```

Really though, the managed method isn't difficult...

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)
```

Be careful when you do this.  In a forms application, you block the message pump and what not, making your program to appear to have hanged.  Rarely is `sleep` a good idea.

Comment: Do one blocks the "message pump" even when calling Sleep on a different Thread such as ``` Dim thread As New Thread(
                      Sub()
                          Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(500)
                          textbox.BackColor = originalColor
                      End Sub)
                thread.Start() ```