# Have a sub or thread sleep or wait without hanging form in VB.net windows forms application

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, wait, thread-sleep

My question is in relation to the following question:

[Sleep function Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191643/sleep-function-visual-basic)

I'm creating a fairly simple windows forms application.  The different threads involved will need to sleep at different times.  I was planning on using sleep to accomplish this similar to the method described in the above thread, but it would be undesirable to have the form appear non-reponsive while the thread is sleeping.  I was wondering what alternative method could be used to have a thread sleep or wait that would not result in the related form becoming non responsive.

I'll be monitoring the question for comments and answers, so if I need to clarify anything just let me know.  As always, I greatly appreciate the knowledge and expertise of this community, and I thank you in advance for you time and consideration.

Comment: Calling `Thread.Sleep` will not make the UI unresponsive *unless* the thread that you are sleeping *is* the UI thread.

Comment: Timers can be a good alternative to Sleep at times.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Ok then, I'll give it a shot using that command.  I was just concerned given the nature of the other post.  I'll post back if it works out.  I'm not new to coding or VB by any means, but this .Net stuff is a new animal to me, but I'm learning quickly and enjoying it.  Hopefully it works out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The post you linked sleeps the `CurrentThread`

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)
```

If the `CurrentThread` happens to be the UI thread, it will appear non-responsive. If you use `CurrentThread` from within your background thread's code, the background thread will be the `CurrentThread` and it will have no impact on your UI.